# Get images from a SharePoint Library

Tags: javascript, office-365, visual-studio-2013

I'm making a Carousel that need to get images by date of a SharePoint Library , all the code of the carousel, and configuration page i have already maked, but i dont have no idea of how i get the images to put on the carousel from de SharePoint Library, i'm a new programmer on SharePoint , someone can help me ?

PS: Using SharePoint Online 2013 (Office 365) , Thanks !!

Answer (score 6):

SharePoint 2013 includes several APIs that could be utilized for that purpose:

- [JavaScript object model (JSOM)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj193034(v=office.15).aspx)
- [REST Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569(v=office.15).aspx)
- [SharePoint SOAP Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee538665(v=office.15).aspx). [SPServices library](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) is commonly used for consuming SP Web Services via JavaScript.

and some another ways.

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve items from Picture library using JSOM. For more details follow [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201(v=office.15).aspx).

```
function getListItems(listTitle,queryText, success,error){
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var query = new SP.CamlQuery();
    query.set_viewXml(queryText);
    var items = list.getItems(query);
    ctx.load(items);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
          success(items);
      },
      error
    );
}

function getPictures(success,error){
   var listTitle = "Pictures";
   var queryText = '<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"/></OrderBy></Query></View>';
   getListItems(listTitle,queryText,
      function(items){
         var pictureEntries = []; 
         for(var i = 0; i < items.get_count();i++) {
            var item = items.getItemAtIndex(i);
            var entry = { 
                'Url': item.get_item('FileRef'), 
                'Name' : item.get_item('Title') 
            };
            pictureEntries.push(entry);
         }
         success(pictureEntries);
      },
      error);
}


getPictures(
   function(entries){
         //Carousel binding goes here...
   },
   function(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message());
   }
);
```

### References

- [Choose the right API set in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

here is the REST API version within a  minimal.masterpage in SharePoint 2013 in a web part page.

I have also added an empty div with id of  pictureMicroGallery at the end of PlaceHolderMain in SharePoint designer.

```
        <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderFooter" runat="server">
        <script src="/_layouts/15/CDN/Js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" > 
        function LoadImages(){
            $.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + 
                    "_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Employees')/Items/?$select=Title,FileLeafRef,FileDirRef,Description" + "&$filter=Author eq 'Mark Twain' and Name ne 'Item' and isManager eq 1" ,
                    type: "GET",
                    headers: {              "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",         },
                    success:  this.success,
                    error: this.failed 
                }
                ); 
         }           

        function success(data, args) {
            var pictureArray = new Array();
            var pictureCount = 0;

            var results = data.d.results; 
            for(var i=0; i<results.length; i++) { 

                var filename = results[i].FileLeafRef  ;
                filename = filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf("."))+"_"+ filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf(".")+1 )+".jpg";   

                var dir =  results[i].FileDirRef  ;
                filename = dir + '/_w/' + filename;
                pictureArray[pictureCount++] = filename;        
            }
            var newHtml = '';
            for(i=0; i<pictureArray.length; i++) {
                newHtml += '<img class="pictureGallery" src="';
                newHtml += pictureArray[i];
                newHtml += '" style="margin:4px;"/>';
            }

          $('#pictureMicroGallery').html(newHtml);            

        }

        function failed(sender, args) {
            $('#pictureMicroGallery').html(args.get_message());
        }

        $(document).ready( function () { 
            LoadImages();   
         });

        </script>
```

Comment: Can I also include a `WHERE` statement in the AJAX call? Thanks.

Comment: @Si8 , yes with $filter and using logical operators like and  eq for equal and ne for not equal. I will update the answer to show range of this capabilities. you can check this samples : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/124864/16880

Comment: Thank you. I am doing the above with C#, however the attachment and the rest of the article is coming separate and not together...