# REST with $filter for List Items in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, rest, filter

Sharepoint 2013, REST API, native C++ application:
I want to get all Folder items from the list. Try

```
/_api/Web/Lists(guid'GUID')/Items?$filter=FileSystemObjectType+eq+1
```

and get HTTP 400 Bed request. Same for `$filter=AuthorId+eq+1` and some other fields.
But e.g. `$filter=Id+eq+1` or `$filter=Modified+eq+'2014-11-01T16:13:49Z'` works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: Explore and Learn SharePoint REST Odata query ($select, $filter, $expand, $top with example): https://bit.ly/39Niz2i

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It does not seem possible to filter list items using [FileSystemObjectType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj244796(v=office.15).aspx) in SharePoint 2013 REST.

### Option 1

But you could utilize the following REST query to return folders and associated list items:

```
/_api/web/lists/Lists(guid'GUID')/rootFolder/Folders?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

**JavaScript example**

```
var listTitle = "Documents"; 
var url = "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/rootFolder/Folders?$expand=ListItemAllFields";
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    //print folders
    $(data.value).each(function(i,folder){
         var folderName = folder.Name;
         var folderItem = folder.ListItemAllFields; //get asssociated List Item with a Folder
    });
});
```

**Update**

In order to exclude "system" folders like `Attachments` you could apply an additional filter like demonstrated below:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('list title')/rootFolder/Folders?$expand=ListItemAllFields&$filter=Name ne 'Attachments' and Name ne 'Item' and Name ne 'Forms'
```

### Option 2

Another approach would be to apply the filtering by Folder via CAML query as demonstrated below:

```
function getListItems(listTitle, queryViewXml)
{
   var queryPayload = { 
       'query':{ 
           '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
           'ViewXml': queryViewXml
        } 
   }; 
   var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems";

   return $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
      }, 
      data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
      url: endpointUrl
   });
}

function getFolderItems(listTitle)
{
    var query = '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>';
    return getListItems(listTitle,query);
}
```

**Usage**

```
//retrieve and print folder item names
getFolderItems('Requests')
.done(function(data){
    var items = data.d.results;
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          console.log(items[i].Title);   
    }
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
});
```

### Option 3

Utilize SharePoint **2010** REST Interface, in particular the following query returns folder items:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Requests?$filter=ContentType eq 'Folder'
```

where `Requests` is the name of a List

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it getting /Folders from the list root folder returns site-related items (e.g. Forms) while I need only those visible to user.

Comment: The answer has been updated, see the update section, in addition an alternative option has been added (option 2).

Comment: Well... Option 1 looks hacky
Are 'Attachments', 'Item' and 'Forms' the only "system" folders which can appear?
Can any other ones appear?
What about "system" files to skip?

Regarding Option 2 - can I do the same with C++? It looks like I do but anyway - what is assumed to be faster: posting Caml query or loading all the list items and filter them manually in C++?

Comment: Option 2 definitely is more clean solution since it returns only user-defined folders. I believe it is doable, see for example here: https://casablanca.codeplex.com/discussions/447077

Comment: Regarding option 1, i'm afraid this is not the complete list of system folders, for example in Assets library contains also _t and _w folders..

Comment: The answer has been updated with an additional option (3)

Comment: What should I use instead of $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() in C++ application?

Comment: This https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7eff63ad7d001d0e4c8f C# example demonstrates how to retrieve Request Digest (see RequestFormDigest method). I hope you could easily convert it into C++ version..

Comment: Does this work for Document Sets as well?

Answer (score 8):

To return files use:

`_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$filter=startswith(ContentTypeId, '0x0101')`

To return folders use:

`_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items?$filter=startswith(ContentTypeId, '0x0120')`

I have tested this against SP2013 Online (O365), it should work against SP2010 as well.
This works against all child content types as the content type id should inherit from the parent as explained [in the MSDN article 'Content Type IDs'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543822(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: By the way, I discovered that $filter can be very confusing because it is applied BEFORE conversion to JSON. If the field is boolean (such as EnableVersioning) you must use $filter=EnableVersioning eq **true**, but if your field an enum, such as Yes/No, you must use a number, such as $filter=CreditApplied eq 0.  EVEN though the enum is mapped to boolean in JSON, you cannot treat it as boolean in the filter.

Comment: this solution return back thumbnail for every video object.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working with DocSets and they are a "folder" type. I'm using

```
url: webURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$filter=FSObjType eq 1"
```

and that is working just fine for me. Before I added that on it was giving me both the docsets and their contents (the contents have FSObjType of 0) and after I added the filter I only have the DocSets and not the children.

Answer (score 4):

this is what worked for me:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LISTNAME')/Items?$orderby=Created desc&$filter=FSObjType+eq+1
```

FileSystemObjectType seems not to work

Answer (score 2):

If you're still trying to figure out the problem with AuthorID i believe it is referenced as Author/ID

here's a snippet of the parameters I use on my code for pulling up the tasks:

```
      var params = {
        URL:"/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('tasks')/Items"
        , params:{
          1:1
          , $select:[
            'Id'
            ,'Title'
            ,'Author/Name'
            ,'Author/FirstName'
            ,'Author/LastName'
            ,'Author/ID'
            ,'Created'
            ,'Modified'
            ,'Status'
            ,'WorkflowOutcome'
            ,'Editor/Name'
            ,'Editor/FirstName'
            ,'Editor/LastName'
            ,'Editor/ID'
            ,'WorkflowItemId'
            ,'WorkflowListId'
            ,'WorkflowLink'
            ].join(",")
          , $expand:'Author/ID,Editor/ID'
          , $filter:"((Created ge datetime'"+$scope.autoApprove.date.start.value.toISOString()+"') and (Created le datetime'"+$scope.autoApprove.date.end.value.toISOString()+"'))"
//          , $filter:"((WorkflowOutcome eq 'Rejected'))"
        }};
```

Answer (score 0):

best and easiest and fastest: [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/130347/5170) : by @john-m [his profile](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/29887/)

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Production_Library/Communication Management')/files
```

filter only the files exist in specific folder

Comment: depends on what is needed. this way will give even auxiliary files no interesting (and not visible) for user on SharePoint web interface

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach:

```
(token, domain, "/_api/web/lists?" + URLEncoder.encode("$select=ID,Title&$filter=basetype ne 1&$orderby=title", "utf-8"));
```