# How to filter for files using rest api ( sharepoint online )?

Tags: 2013, jquery, rest

Why doesn't the following string returns data from within a folder in the same asset library:

Asset Library Name is Production_Library

Folder Name is at the top level of the asset library and is named Communication Management

The filter works nicely here at the /items level filtering against the Business Process field.

```
https://gumdrops.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('production_library')/items?$filter=Business_x0020_Process eq 'Communication Management'
```

However, the filter doesn't work at all here within the folders against the Name Field.

```
https://gumdrops.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('production_library')/files?$filter=Name eq 'Communication Management'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting items in folders with the REST API is a bit different than selecting items in the library itself... (like in your first example)

The way that I get the items in a specific folder is with the `/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("<serverRelativeFolderUrl>")/files` endpoint...

So in your example, you want everything in `Production_Library/Communication Management` (notice that you don't have to url encode the space)

I'm assuming that `Production_Library` sits at the root of your site, so your path may be slightly different, but to get all of the items in the `Communication Management` folder you would use a request to:

```
/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Production_Library/Communication Management')/files
```

Your second request in the question would actually go to the `/files` endpoint against the `Production_Library` document library and look for a file that has a `Name` of `Communication Management` -- which you've noticed doesn't work... A request like that returns a 400 error for me in SharePoint online when I try to filter the `/files` endpoint by `Name` -- but even if it did work you wouldn't be getting the items inside of the folder like you're looking for.

Comment: good comment, but doesn't help the cause.

Comment: I think you'll find the endpoint I suggested "returns data from within a folder in the same asset library" as your question asks -- otherwise you may need to clarify what you are looking for.

Comment: John, sorry about that and Big Thanks. I took another look at it. GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl works perfectly. Now, I need to figure out how to filter for files ending with .docx & .pdf .

Answer (score 3):

Your second query just returns files filtered by `File.Name` and nothing more.

The following examples demonstrates how to retrieve files from a specific folder.

### How to retrieve Files from a specific Folder using SharePoint REST

Assume a `Documents` library contains `Guides` folder.

**Option 1**

Using [SP.Web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245434%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Endpoint Uri: GET `/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('documents/guides')/files`

**Option 2**

Using CAML query

Endpoint Uri: POST `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/getitems`

Body:

```
{  
      'query' : {
                 '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                 'ViewXml' : '<View><Query/></View>',
                 'FolderServerRelativeUrl': '/Documents/Guides'  
       }
}
```

Headers:

- `X-RequestDigest: value`
- `Accept: application/json; odata=verbose`
- `Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose`

Comment: Vadim, thanks. I'm not sure how to implement the caml querries, so I'll try to see if I can get this to work. It appears to be a bit more effective.

Comment: This is a nice technique for combining a CAML query with the REST API that I hadn't seen before -- thanks Vadim!

Comment: how to get the folders from asset library

Comment: Is there any way to mention the FolderServerRelativeUrl  inside the viewXml? Like the Queryoptions node has a folder node. Does that work with SharePoint 2013?