# Retrieve folders and sub folders from document library by REST call

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, office-365, folder

I need to get a list of folders and sub folders from document library. I feel that approaching this problem using REST call would be easier than the traditional CSOM query. Please suggest a relevant approach and solution.

Answer (score 7):

You could utilize [GetItems method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListGetItems) and specify the following query:

```
<View Scope="RecursiveAll">
     <Query>
         <Where>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="Integer">1</Value>
            </Eq>
         </Where>
     </Query>
</View>
```

to return *all folder items* in a library.

**Example**

```
function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, viewXml) 
{
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml
               }
    };

    return $.ajax({
           url: url,
           method: "POST",
           contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
           data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
           headers: {
              "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
              "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
           }
     });
}

function getAllFolderItems(webUrl,listTitle)
{
    var viewXml = '<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>';
    return getListItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewXml);
}
```

**Usage**

```
//print folder names from Documents library
getAllFolderItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Documents')
.done(function(data)
{
     var items = data.d.results;
     for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
         console.log(items[i].Title);
     }    
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: I am unable to get the folder and sub folder names. When I added this code it returned me object. I don't know how to go ahead now. Can you please suggest me the next steps.

Answer (score 7):

Recently I answered a very similar question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138135/get-all-files-and-folders-in-one-call/138139#138139). If you need all of the folders and subfolders (but no documents) recursively from a document library, that is what you should use (send it via POST to the server due to `GetItems` method call):

```
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Title of your doc. lib.')/GetItems(query=@v1)?$expand=Folder&$select=Title,Folder/ServerRelativeUrl&@v1={"ViewXml":"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"}
```

Alternatively, you could use the following REST query as well (via HTTP GET):

```
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Title of your doc. lib.')/Items?$expand=Folder&$select=Title,Folder/ServerRelativeUrl
```

It will return all of the items (documents and folders) in you library, you should filter them on the client side based on the `FileSystemObjectType` property, as you can't use this one in the `$filter` expression in REST (see details [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124846/rest-with-filter-for-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013)).

Last, but not least, you can use the SharePoint 2010 compatible REST Interface as shown in [option 3](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124846/rest-with-filter-for-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013):

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/YourDocLib?$filter=ContentType eq 'Folder'
```

Note, that the syntax is language-specific in this case. The query above is OK for English, but for German it would be:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/YourDocLib?$filter=Inhaltstyp eq 'Ordner'
```