# Full Tree View in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want to achieve a full tree view of my site hierarchy and the documents in there. So I would be able to see the full tree view of the site hierarchy from any site.

It isn't possible to do with the "tree view" or "quick start" areas from what I understand.

Any tip on how to do this in SharePoint Online? Maybe with the help of SharePoint Designer?

Actually a webpart containing such a full tree view would be great, since I could use it in a template.

Answer (score 1):

How comfortable are you with JavaScript, REST, Asynchronous processing?

The information you want is not available with one call, you have to **recursively** process Webs and Lists

#### Starting points:

- [Retrieve folders and sub folders from document library by REST call](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140134/retrieve-folders-and-sub-folders-from-document-library-by-rest-call)
- [Get all Files and Folders in one call](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138135/get-all-files-and-folders-in-one-call)