# With REST recursively retrieve file and folder directory structure

Tags: document-library, rest, folder, file

I have a site which is running under SharePoint 2013. Via REST I am trying to retrieve the file and folder directory for that site. There are several similar questions on this site related to recursively retrieving all of the files and folders for a given a folder:

- [Retrieve folders and sub folders from document library by REST call](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/140134/47689)
- [Get all Files and Folders in one call](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/138135/47689)

The answers provided therein led me to the following URI:

> /_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/Items?$expand=Folder&$select=Title,FileLeafRef,Folder/ServerRelativeUrl

Which from what I can tell does retrieve all of the files and folders from the given starting path.

However, I am missing something. When reading through the returned XML I cannot figure out where a given file goes. Meaning that I have info on how to retrieve file `bros.pdf`, but cannot determine that it is in the `documents/super/mario/` folder.

For the file items I've tried to retrieve the `ServerRelativeUrl` property, but have not succeeded though the folders seem to. Is there some identifier in the XML that I am missing? When doing a recursive RESTful query how do I determine where a given file belongs?

Answer (score 5):

You are probably looking for `FileRef` property instead of (or in addition to) `FileLeafRef` property.

> `FileRef` property returns server relative file/folder url

The following query demonstrates how to retrieve the `name` and `url` of every file and folder in `Documents` library:

```
/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef
```

Answer (score 0):

Please expand the File as well, then you can obtain the ServerRelativeUrl property of File.

```
_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Documents')/Items?$expand=Folder,File&$select=Title,FileLeafRef,Folder/ServerRelativeUrl, File/ServerRelativeUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Lists/getbyTitle('" + LibraryName + "')/Items?$select=FileLeafRef,FileRef,Id&$top=5000
```

use this URL. but after fetching data you need to traverse through FileRef so you can get your exact folder Location.
Some custom coding required.