# Retrieve List Item from a SP List item folder using CSOM

Tags: list, rest, csom, jsom, folder

I have created some folders in SharePoint 2013 List and added some items into this.
Now I want to fetch items from a specific folder using javascript or maybe REST.
Please provide me with the solution.

Note its a custom SP list, not Library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rest API to fetch all items from  SharePoint list. Below is sample code to fetch all items from SharePoint list using Rest API.

```
function getListItems(webUrl, listTitle, viewXml) {
var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems";
var queryPayload = {
    'query': {
        '__metadata': {
            'type': 'SP.CamlQuery'
        },
        'ViewXml': viewXml
    }
};
return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    data: JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
    headers: {
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    }
});
}
function getAllFolderItems(webUrl, listTitle) {
var viewXml = '<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FSObjType" /><Value Type="Integer">1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>';
var data = getListItems(webUrl, listTitle, viewXml);
data.done(function(data) {
    var items = data.d.results;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        console.log(items[i].Title);
    }
}).fail(
    function(error) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

References : [Retrieve folders and sub folders from document library by REST call](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140134/retrieve-folders-and-sub-folders-from-document-library-by-rest-call)

[Working with folders and files with REST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am using some alternate solution using javascript and it worked. I am adding solution below as Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add added one more line above CAML Query.

```
  camlQuery.set_folderServerRelativeUrl("/Lists/PINCODE/FolderName"); 
 camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View ><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef" Name='columnName' />"<Value Type='Text'>" + SomeValue + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View > ");
```